# В чем различие пакетов от обычных папок с файлами в Python

Tags: python

Какой смысл в пакетах ( кроме файла `__init__.py` ), если мы можем просто использовать точно также папку с файлами, то есть иметь доступ к аргументам и функциям через точку?

Answer (score 2):

Пакет - это объект управление менеджером пакетов (pip, еаsy_install ...).

Менеджеры предоставляют:

1. удобство распространения. Пакеты могут быть написаны не только на питоне, а включать в себя dll (*.pyc) файлы, сборка которых под каждую платформу, потребует отдельного компилятора (для языка программирования на котором пакет написан), у каждого пользователя.
2. контроль зависимостей. Если пакет использует 10 других пакетов, а те еще по 10, то ручной поиск всех зависимостей мог бы занять много времени.
3. контроль совместимости версий пакетов и централизованное обновление.

А технически, пакет и есть папка.